# How to internally mutate custom FormControl value and emit new value programmatically

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, controlvalueaccessor

I have a custom form control that implements `ControlValueAccessor`. I initialize the reactive form group and control with a value. I want to mutate that value internally inside the control component and have the outer form get that mutated value.

This works fine to emit the `onChange()` event when I interact with the control and a new value is set through the UI, however that initial value (set through `FormBuilder`) does not trigger a `form.valueChanges` event when it internally changes, so the form never has the modified value if you never change the value of the control through the UI.

The only way I've figured out how to ensure that the form sees the mutated value is to wrap a `setTimeout` around the `this.onChange(this.value)` call, which seems wrong. Trying figure out if anyone has tried this and found a better solution than `setTimeout`?

Here's a very stripped down stackblitz to show the scenario: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t28bst?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-control%2Fform-control.component.ts

You can see that the value internally is "hello world" whereas the form outside shows only "hello", unless you click the Update Value button inside the control (which just sets `value = value`) and then the form sees it. Alternatively, you can uncomment the `setTimeout` around the `onChange()` call and see that works too.

Comment: Not sure about your issue in particular but consider using https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form under the hood it works with ControlValueAccessor but will save you a lot of time/boilerplate/headaches :)

Comment: hmm, interesting, @maxime1992. I'm not sure if that will help my issue, but worth looking into. I've definitely written a lot of copy-pasted boilerplate for ControlValueAccessors. thanks

Comment: I've taken your example and turned it into an ngx-sub-form, let me know if it helps :) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3wbarp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-control%2Fform-control.component.ts

Comment: ok, wow, I'm not sure if I performed the mutation where it's expected, but it seems to work without a setTimeout at least: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zprpj8?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Oooh I think I get what you want now! And yes definitely, the `transformToFormGroup` hook is there for that :)

Comment: Although this helper did create a solution to my problem without the need for `setTimeout` I'm wondering if there is a true solution that doesn't necessarily require an additional dependency. any ideas?

Comment: Digging into the source of ngx-sub-form, it looks like this works as I wanted because it actually uses `setTimeout` under the hood too. Maybe this can't be done without it? wish I could test this without async